# Pass JSON key in function

Tags: javascript, json, parameters, key

Is it possible to specify the key of an object as a function parameter? For example, if I wanted to create a filter function that could filter several map markers by marker.element.country or marker.element.population?

This way I could write `filter("England", country)` and `filter(100000, population)`

```
var markers = [...some array of JSON objects];
function filter(value, filterBy){
    markers.forEach(function (marker) {
        marker.setVisible(marker.element[filterBy] == value);
        //marker.setVisible(marker.element.filterBy == value); -didn't work either
    });
};
```

I'm not looking for a work around. I know I could code several separate functions or create some conditional within this function that behaves differently based on the value of `filterBy`.

**This is no fun:**

```
var markers = [...some array of JSON objects];
function filter(value, filterBy){
    if(filterBy == "country"){
        markers.forEach(function (marker) {
            marker.setVisible(marker.element.country == value);
        });
    }
    if(filterBy == "population"){
        markers.forEach(function (marker) {
            marker.setVisible(marker.element.population == value);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Your two functions are functionally equivalent. Does the second one work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can use the standard array `filter` function to achieve it:

```js
var markers = [ { country: 'England', population: 1000}, {country: 'Italy', population: 50}];
function customfilter(value, filterBy){
  return markers.filter(function(el) {
   if(el.hasOwnProperty(filterBy) && el[filterBy] === value) {
      return el;
    }
  });
};
console.log(customfilter('Italy', 'country'));
```